# Parsing start and end date with sed

Tags: bash, parsing, sed

Please can someone let me know how I would turn this:

```
part1-part2-part3-2012-07-23-2012-07-23.csv
```

into this:

```
part1-part2-part3.csv
```

The `part1-part2-part3` is a substitution for another string, so shouldn't be treated as constant.

I believe `sed` is probably the best tool for the job, and although I could work this out in time, I'm working to a tight schedule.

Any help really appreciated.

Comment: I've gone with @codaddict on this one, but thank you all for your input - really appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ echo 'part1-part2-part3-2012-07-23-2012-07-23.csv' |  \
  sed -re 's/^(.*)(-[0-9]+){6}(.*)$/\1\3/'
part1-part2-part3.csv
```

Answer (score 0):

This `sed` command does the job. It matches one date and use it as group 1 for the second match, because they are identical.

```
sed -e 's/\(-[0-9]\{4\}-[0-9]\{2\}-[0-9]\{2\}\)\1\(\.csv\)$/\2/'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$ echo part1-part2-part3-2012-07-23-2012-07-23.csv | sed 's/-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]//'
part1-part2-part3.csv
```

Also, if you know that you need to remove all characters from -2012 to the end of line
you can do it simpler:

```
$ echo part1-part2-part3-2012-07-23-2012-07-23.csv | sed 's/-2012.*/.csv/'
```

Answer (score 0):

**Input.txt**

```
part1-part2-part3-2012-07-23-2012-07-23.csv
```

**Code**

> $>   sed 's/[0-9][0-9]//g' Input.txt | sed 's/---*//g'

**Output**

```
part1-part2-part3.csv
```

Answer (score 0):

http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Field-Separators.html

```
echo part1-part2-part3-2012-07-23-2012-07-23.csv | \
awk -v FS='-2012-07[^.]*' '{print $1 $2}'
```

Answer (score 0):

`cut` is a littler simpler than `sed` in this case:

```
fname=part1-part2-part3-2012-07-23-2012-07-23.csv
new_fname="$(echo $fname | cut -d- -f1-3).csv"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$ echo part1-part2-part3-2012-07-23-2012-07-23.csv |
> awk -F '-' '{ print $1"-"$2"-"$3".csv" }'
part1-part2-part3.csv
```